# IE browser not launching in Windows /Linux jenkins & My tests all hang on the "This is the initial start page" Selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, driver

```
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
 INFO [main] (PropertiesRepository.java:19)- Loading property file : TestConfig.properties
 INFO [main] (PropertiesRepository.java:19)- Loading property file : log4j.properties
 INFO [main] (BaseTest.java:61)- Start logging
 INFO [main] (BaseTest.java:63)- Start logging started 
 INFO [main] (WebDriverManager.java:882)- Reading https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/ to seek IEDriverServer
 INFO [main] (WebDriverManager.java:631)- Exporting webdriver.ie.driver as C:\Users\pebuild\.m2\repository\webdriver\IEDriverServer\Win32\3.150\IEDriverServer.exe
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
3.150.0.0
Listening on port 15052
Only local connections are allowed
Aug 17, 2020 5:19:36 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
 INFO [main] (WebDriverFactory.java:59)- IE driver instance is launched successfully
```

loading but not executing

Comment: I suppose you tested other browsers as well, and they work fine?

Comment: chrome working but ie browser having issue loading up to 8 hours after that getting exceptionorg.openqa.selenium.ScriptTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for script to complete.

Comment: There're some required configurations need to be set before you automate IE. You could refer to [this link](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration) and check if you have met all the requirements. You can also check if you're using the recommended IEDriver version in [this page](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).